# JQuery Templates: pass parameter into a function

Tags: jquery-templates

So I have this JQuery template that calls a function:

```
<script id="Fred" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
  <td>${functionX()}${Field2}</td>
</script>
```

Works great.  but now I want to pass a parameter into it, but the following won't work.

```
<script id="Fred" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
  <td>${functionX(${Field1})}${Field2}</td>
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can access Field1 directly without using ${, like:

```
<td>${functionX(Field1)}${Field2}</td>
```

Comment: Awesome. This works. Doesn't seem like it should, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out:

```
<td>${functionX($data.Field1)}${Field2}</td>
```

Comment: this is apparently just *another way* of doing it.  The accepted answer is a great way as well.

Comment: $data is implied.  So, $data.Field1 and Field1 are the same (also $item.data.Field1).  $data does become really useful though when you want to pass the entire object to something.

Answer (score -1):

This is another example of how the problem could be solved:

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{if title.length}}
    <h3>${title}</h3>
    <p>Start: ${ render($data) } :End</p>
    {{/if}}
</script>
```

You can see that this method works in [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/SXvsZ/445/).